# Low of specific period (eg: 20 jan 2015 to 15 nov 2021)

Tags: excel, pine-script, trading

[image: Image for reference]

This script draws ATH on chart with date and duration
I want to store low of period as well (like high shown in label) to show (high-low) range in the same label. The period does not end today, but as per script.

```
indicator("Previous Year(s) ATH", overlay = true)

num_years = input.int(1, title = "Number of years back", minval = 1)

var float ATH = high
var int ATH_time = time

var float[] ATH_vals = array.new_float()
var int[] ATH_time_vals = array.new_int()
var int[] ATH_time_change_vals = array.new_int()

ATH := math.max(ATH, high)
if ta.change(ATH) != 0
    ATH_time := time
    
array.unshift(ATH_vals, ATH)
array.unshift(ATH_time_vals, time)
array.unshift(ATH_time_change_vals, ATH_time)

var float ATH1Y = na

if barstate.isconfirmed
    search_time = time - 31536000000 * num_years
    for i = 0 to array.size(ATH_time_vals) - 1
        if array.get(ATH_time_vals, i) < search_time
            ATH1Y := array.get(ATH_vals, i)
            ATH1Y_time = array.get(ATH_time_change_vals, i)
            y = year(ATH1Y_time)
            m = month(ATH1Y_time)
            d = dayofmonth(ATH1Y_time)
            days_ago = (time - ATH1Y_time) / 86400000
            date_text = str.tostring(y) + "/" + str.tostring(m) + "/" + str.tostring(d) + " : " + str.tostring(ATH1Y) + "\nDays Ago : " + str.tostring(math.round(days_ago, 2))

            if ATH > ATH1Y and ATH[3] <= ATH1Y[3]
                label.new(x = bar_index[3], y = ATH[3], text = date_text, style = label.style_label_lower_right)
            break

ATH_val = ATH > ATH1Y ? na : ATH1Y

buy_signal = ATH > ATH1Y and ATH[3] <= ATH1Y[3]

plotshape(buy_signal, color = color.green, location = location.belowbar, size = size.small, style = shape.triangleup)

plot(ATH_val, title = "ATH", style = plot.style_linebr)
```